# How can I prevent users from using the backspace or delete keys in a textbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keypress

How can I prevent users from using the backspace or delete keys in a textbox using JavaScript?

I have a text box in my web form. I want to use JavaScript on keypress of the textbox to disable the delete and backspace keys.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you can explain the scenario then it would be helpful.

Comment: Don't forget `Ctrl-X`, choosing `Cut` from the menu, or the insert key.  There are lots of ways to remove text from an input.

Comment: Or selecting a block of text (with mouse or Ctrl+a or Shift+cursor) and then staring to type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why are you letting people edit the contents of the text box but restricting them from being able to use basic editing keys? This sounds like you are creating a major usability issue - what if the user makes a typo?

I'd recommend either setting the readonly flag (if you don't want users to edit the value) or disabled flag (if you don't even want it submitted)

Comment: Seconded. Always avoid surprising users with functionality that they don't expect.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit of code to block the certain key press events - or something along those lines (haven't tested the code).

```
function isValidKey(e)
{
    var charCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (charCode == 8 || charCode == 46)
        return false;

    return true;
}

<input id="tb_box" onkeydown="return isValidKey(event)" type="text" />
```

Comment: Is it working or am I doing something wrong ? Only backspace is working on FireFox but not IE.

Comment: IE does not fire the keypress event for some non-character keys (e.g. delete, end, enter, escape, fkeys, etc.).

Comment: Replace onkeypress with onkeydown.

Comment: I tend to shorten it to: var charCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

Answer (score 0):

using javascript create function takes the event keyboard typing then avoid backspace (key-code 8) and delete (key-code 46) keys

```js
function preventBackspace(e) {
  var evt = e || window.event;
  if (evt) {
      var keyCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
      if (keyCode === 8 || keyCode === 46) {
          if (evt.preventDefault) {
              evt.preventDefault();
          } else {
              evt.returnValue = false;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<input onKeyDown="preventBackspace()" placeholder="Try write Something and enter backspace...">
```